# Java - Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: java, eclipse, websocket, glassfish

I have searched for this problem but it didn't work on my project and I don't know why it happened.
Im just doing a simple chat using websocket in java, follow this link:
http://www.programmingforliving.com/2013/07/jsr356-java-api-websocket-jee7-glassfish.html

But when I run project (Im using Eclipse Mars and Glassfish 4), this error happened:

**"WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/websocket/chat' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404"**

Can someone tell me how to solve it. Im just a newbie in java network.
Thanks so much.